# Does panel have a method or property to return text of all text boxes?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a form;

I have a panel containing Text Boxes for user input;

Panel_Details

//inputs from user//

NameTextBox (name)
PhoneNumberTextBox (phone number)
AddressTextBox (address)

Is there a way to write everything in the panel without needing the below code? (IE writeline every textbox )

Currently its like this ;

```
writer.WriteLine(NameTextBox.Text);
writer.WriteLine(PhoneNumberTextBox.Text);
writer.WriteLine(AddressTextBox.Text);
```

I was hoping for something more simple like

```
writer.WriteLine(Panel_details.Text);
```

Comment: I assume it's not the real problem that you are trying to solve. Just for learning purpose, I shared some ideas.

Comment: That's correct as I had already written out each line , I was more so wondering if i ever run into this again if there was such a concept to save time/make it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's not such a magical method, but you can have something like this:

```
var lines = panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
    .OrderBy(x => x.TabIndex)
    .Select(x => x.Text).ToArray();
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("your file path", lines);
```

Above code assumes you set the `TabIndex` of the controls to determine the order that they should appear in the file.

A more clean solution which doesn't have any dependency to the UI and the appearance and order of the controls is having a model and save that model. You can also use data binding to show/edit the model in the form's control:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name}\n{PhoneNumber}\n{Address}";
    }
}
```

You can instantiate an initialize it, for example in `person` field, then to show/edit an instance of person in your form:

```
 nameTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", person, "Name");
 phoneNumberTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", person, "PhoneNumber");
 addressTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", person, "Address");
```

Then whenever you want to save an instance of the person:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("your file path", person.ToString());
```

Comment: I guess you wish the answer was "Yes it has such a method", but unfortunately the answer is "No it doesn't have such a method". So I believe the post answers your question and it would be nice if you accept and upvote the post.